# Event JavaScript when Esc on click?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

How to make the event when the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key is pressed; please give me an example of an `alert ();`.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.body.onkeyup = function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 27){
        alert('Yay');
    }
}
```

Comment: Whatever happened to just [`document.body`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.body)? What about [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener)?

Answer (score 0):

if your interested in using `jquery`,
check this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$("CssSelector").on("keyup", HandleKeyEvent(e));

function HandleKeyEvent(e)
{
    if ( e.keyCode == 27 && e.key == "Escape" )
    {
        //--> Do Something
        alert("It Works");
    }

} );

</script>
```

Sorry I have just realized that this is an old question from 2011.